# How do I display a backround image without setting its width in a div

Tags: css

The problem is that I have more divs so when I set the width of a div in CSS so that the image could be displayed everything gets messed up. I tried to do it by using classes and an ID but it doesn't work. If I don't type its width into a div it doesn't display at all. .GS is a class located in an empty div.

```
div{

 width: 400px;
}

.GS{
background: url("./SS.png");`
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. _«I tried to do it by using classes and an ID but it doesn't work.»_ : please show an attempt including the **minimal** markup you've tried in runnable snippet included in the question itself.

Comment: The background image will require you to set a width and sometimes also a height. If you really don't want to set a width maybe consider using the HTML image tag in stead.